# How to keep breakpoints between sessions using cdb (windbg command line)?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, cdb

My goal is to keep breakpoints between debugging sessions in CDB (the command line version of windbg). I am able to correctly restart by using `.restart`, however I always lose my breakpoints (I am setting my breakpoints by using the `bu` and/or `bm` commands.

Is it even possible when using just cdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cdb is not possible use .bpcmds before .restart and save to someplace and reuse it after restart

for windbg  you can use workspaces to save breakpoints between sessions

edit a demo

suppose you have these breakpoints

```
0:000> bl
 0 e 00007ff6`0fc4109c     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!wWinMain
 1 e 00007ff6`0fc41820     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!wWinMainCRTStartup
 2 e 00007ff6`0fc41960     0001 (0001)  0:**** calc!matherr
 3 e 00007ffb`f033d880     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!NtCreateTimer2
 4 e 00007ffb`f033d6a0     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!NtCreateNamedPipeFile
 5 e 00007ffb`f02a2000     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!RtlDefaultNpAcl+0x190
 6 e 00007ffb`ede53000     0001 (0001)  0:**** KERNELBASE!EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation+0x60
```

.bpcmds will show you how set them (the last two are symbol less bps based on rva )

and if you had set them using bp they may not work  the next time
due to ASLR as the module may be loaded at a different Address

```
0:000> .bpcmds
bu0 calc!wWinMain;
bu1 calc!wWinMainCRTStartup;
bu2 calc!wsetargv;
bu3 ntdll!ZwCreateTimer2;
bu4 ntdll!ZwCreateNamedPipeFile;
bu5 ntdll+2000;
bu6 kernelbase+3000;
0:000>
```

copy paste to some scratch space and after .restart copy paste back to cdb console

you can use **.logopen {some_path_to_some_textfile} do .bpcmds and .restart also**

in this case  you can copy paste the bps from logfile and don't have to open  the log file again as windbg/cdb doesn't close  the logfile on .restart

here is .restart also capturted  to logfile

```
bu6 kernelbase+3000;
0:000> .restart
CommandLine: calc
```